# Sorting List of Lists with for loops

Tags: python, list

I wanted to sort my list of lists and assign them individually according to their respective category. I am still unfamiliar with list indices and how they work. Can someone help me with this?

**Input**

```
2

100 10

200 20
```

**Desired Output**

```
[100, 200]
[10, 20]
```

Code:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    number_of_items = int(input())
    the_items = []

    for i in range(number_of_items):
        the_items.append(input().split(' '))

    for x in the_items:
        cost, disc = [the_items[0][0]], [the_items[0][1]]
        print(cost, disc)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

Python has built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function which will help you here:

```
a = [100, 20]
b = [200, 10]

sorted_ls = [sorted(each) for each in zip(a, b)]
# -> [[100, 200], [10, 20]]
```

Answer (score 0):

So based on what you want and is a little bit confused. Here is the answer:

```
t = int(input())
_t1 = []
_t2 = []
for i in range(t):
    _a = list(map(int,input().split()))
    x = _a[0]
    y = _a[1]
    _t1.append(x)
    _t2.append(y)
print(sorted(_t1))
print(sorted(_t2))
```